# Where can I find a Javascript version of the timepicker in android 4.2.2 alarm clock?

Tags: javascript, android, time, picker

This is the fastest way I've seen to input time on touch devices. I've hunted high and low for a javascript version, but can't locate one.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0B4Hj.png

I'm willing to code one, but only after making sure I'm not duplicating someone elses work.

Has anyone run across one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use the native time type input?

```
  <input type="time" />
```

Comment: Because none of the browsers I've tried on Android give me the great picker as in the alarm clock. Chrome gives me a typical Android time scroller as does Opera. The default browser and Dolphin just show a regular keyboard when the input is in focus.

Comment: I would still recommend it, the user would be used to what ever kind of experience it will receive, where as you are trying to force your favourite experience upon the user.

Comment: You raise a valid point for people who are used to using smartphones. Our users are plumbers who are just starting to learn smartphones, and I would like to make it as easy as possible (and as quick as possible). I'll mark this answer as the best, even though I'm still on the hunt for a javascript version of the time-picker as explained on the top post.